# How to use two tables for single extension and show results in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am making an extension in Magento and trying to get data from two tables to show in a block. I was wondering how to cater and define both tables in Model and extensions config.xml file ?

The code written by me is as following:

config.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pfay_Test>
      <version>0.1.0</version>    
    </Pfay_Test>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <testfrontend>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Pfay_Test</module>
          <frontName>test</frontName>
        </args>
      </testfrontend>
    </routers>
    <layout>
     <updates>
      <test>
       <file>test.xml</file>
     </test>
   </updates>
 </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
 <blocks>
   <test>
    <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
  </test>
</blocks>

<models>

  <test>
   <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
   <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
 </test>

 <test_mysql4>
   <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
   <entities>
     <test>
       <table>pfay_test</table>
     </test>
   </entities>
 </test_mysql4> 

</model>

<resources>
  <test_write>
    <connection>
      <use>core_write</use>
    </connection>
  </test_write>
</resources>

</global>
</config>
```

My Model Hierarchy is as following:

```
-->Model
   -->Test.php
   -->Mysql4
      -->Test.php
      -->Test
         -->Collection.php
```

Where as respected code in the files is as following:

Test.php in Model:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Test.php in Mysql4:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('test/test', 'id_pfay_test');
     }
}
```

Collection.php code in Test Folder:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 {
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within entities tag you can define another table with tag.
For example

```
<entities>
 <test>
   <table>pfay_test</table>
 </test>
 <test2>
   <table>pfay_test2</table>
 </test2>
</entities>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in the following way and it worked.

The code written by me is as following:

config.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pfay_Test>
      <version>0.1.0</version>    
    </Pfay_Test>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <testfrontend>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Pfay_Test</module>
          <frontName>test</frontName>
        </args>
      </testfrontend>
    </routers>
    <layout>
     <updates>
      <test>
       <file>test.xml</file>
     </test>
   </updates>
 </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
 <blocks>
   <test>
    <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
  </test>
</blocks>
<models>
  <test>
    <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
  </test>

  <test_mysql4>
    <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
    <entities>
      <test>
        <table>pfay_test</table>
      </test>
      <test2>
        <table>poll</table>
      </test2>
    </entities>
  </test_mysql4>
</models>
<resources>
  <test_write>
    <connection>
      <use>core_write</use>
    </connection>
  </test_write>
  <test_read>
    <connection>
      <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
  </test_read>
</resources>

</global>
</config>
```

My Model Hierarchy is as following:

```
-->Model
   -->Test.php
   -->Test2.php
   -->Mysql4
      -->Test.php
      -->Test2.php
      -->Test
         -->Collection.php
      -->Test2
         -->Collection.php
```

Where as respected code in the files is as following:

Test.php in Model:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Test2.php in Model:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Test2 extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test2');
     }
}
```

Test.php in Mysql4:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('test/test', 'id_pfay_test');
     }
}
```

Test2.php in Mysql4:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test2 extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         $this->_init('test/test2', 'poll_id');
     }
}
```

Collection.php code in Test Folder:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 {
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```

Collection.php code in Test2 Folder:

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4_Test2_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 {
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test2');
     }
}
```

And Usage in the block was:

```
public function methodblock()
    {
        //on initialize la variable
        $retour='';
        /* we are doing the query to select all elements of the pfay_test table (thanks to our model test/test and we sort them by id_pfay_test */
        $collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()
        ->setOrder('id_pfay_test','asc');

         //then, we check the result of the query and with the function getData() 
        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
            $retour .= $data->getData('nom').' '.$data->getData('prenom').' '.$data->getData('telephone').'<br />';
        }
         //i return a success message to the user thanks to the Session.

        $collection2 = Mage::getModel('test/test2')->getCollection()
        ->setOrder('poll_id','asc');

        foreach($collection2 as $data)
        {
            $retour .= $data->getData('poll_title').' '.$data->getData('votes_count').' '.$data->getData('date_posted').'<br />';
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Cool Ca marche !!');
        return $retour;
    }
```